# Can't assign PathFindExtensionW output to an array of WCHAR

Tags: c, winapi, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I want to assign the output of `PathFindExtensionW` api to an array of WCHAR. this api return a LPWSTR pointer. I searched and find out the method of assigning a LPWSTR to an array of WCHAR is like following:

`WCHAR array[100] = PathFindExtensionW(,,,)`

but it doesn't work for me and I receive this error:

**expression must be a modifiable lvalue**

I'm using VS 2012. my code is as following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Shlwapi.h"

#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int iToSizeB = 0;
    iToSizeB = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1 , NULL, 0);

    WCHAR lpFileAddress[260] = {0};
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1, lpFileAddress, iToSizeB);

    WCHAR lpDotPosition[260] = {0};

    //this line must be correct but I receive error
    lpDotPosition = PathFindExtensionW(lpFileAddress);

    int iToSizeW = 0;
    iToSizeW = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, lpDotPosition, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    CHAR lpExtension[260] = {0};
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, lpDotPosition, -1, lpExtension, iToSizeW, NULL, NULL);

    printf("the format is:\n");
    printf(lpExtension);
    printf("\n");

    getchar();
}
```

what's wrong with this?

thank's for your solutions.

Comment: C doesn't let you assign arrays like that. If you really want `lpDotPosition` to be an array you need to use a function to copy the data into it (e.g. `strcpy` or a safer variant). But I suspect you just want a pointer, not an array - try `LPCWSTR lpDotPosition;` instead.

Comment: I use array because I should use a static memory allocation. and so, `LPCWSTR ` declaration should be dynamic. how should I declare that function? assign characters of pointer to every index of array?

Comment: I can't see why you need `lpDotPosition` to be an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot populate an array by assigning a pointer to it. You have to copy the data, such as with [`lstrcpynW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lstrcpynw) or similar function:

```
LPCWSTR lpDotPosition = PathFindExtensionW(lpFileAddress);

WCHAR lpExtensionW[MAX_PATH] = {0};
lstrncpy(lpExtensionW, lpDotPosition, MAX_PATH);
```

However, `PathFindExtension()` simply returns a pointer inside the string buffer that you pass in, so there is no need to allocate a separate copy of the extension, the data has already been allocated beforehand, and the returned pointer will remain valid for as long as the input string is valid:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WCHAR lpFileAddress[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    int iToSizeB = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1, lpFileAddress, MAX_PATH);

    LPCWSTR lpDotPosition = PathFindExtensionW(lpFileAddress);

    CHAR lpExtension[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    int iToSizeW = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, lpDotPosition, -1, lpExtension, MAX_PATH, NULL, NULL);

    printf("the format is:\n%s\n", lpExtension);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, there is no need to use `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` just to search a `char` string, you can use `PathFindExtensionA()` instead:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LPCSTR lpExtension = PathFindExtensionA(argv[1]);

    printf("the format is:\n%s\n", lpExtension);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In fact, as used in the code, calling `MultiByteToWideChar` with `CP_UTF8` is a bug. The real fix is to use the wide character version of the entry point, and use wide character versions of the API. User input (particularly with file names) is outside your control, and the only feasible way to deal with it is to use Unicode (UTF-16LE) throughout.